# Adventure Works SQL Server 2014 Enquiry

Tags: sql, sql-server, adventureworks

I am writing a SQL query using the `AdventureWorks` 2014 database. I want to show which employee has sold for the highest order value.

I tried to write each select statement by itself (see below), but I'd like to be able to combine both queries into one:

```
select 
    s.SalesOrderID, s.SalesPersonID, COUNT(sd.SalesOrderID) as count 
from 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader s, Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
where 
    s.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID 
group by           
    sd.SalesOrderID, s.SalesOrderID, s.SalesPersonID 
order by 
    sd.SalesOrderID

select 
    sd.SalesOrderID, sd.LineTotal, count (sd.SalesOrderID) as count 
from 
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
group by 
    sd.SalesOrderID, sd.LineTotal 
order by 
    sd.SalesOrderID
```

[image]

Comment: Did the 2 queries work? Highest order value, I would think be a `SUM()` function. Remove `sd.SalesOrderID` from the `Group By` since that is an aggregate.

Comment: Remove `s.SalesOrderID ` from the top query to get the `Count()` for each `s.SalesPersonID`. Remove from the `Select` and `Group By`. Change the `Order By` to the `s.SalesPersonID`

Comment: @WEI_DBA   can you write the new query to me please

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like this:

```
select top 1  
    s.SalesPersonID
    ,sum(sd.LineTotal ) as orderTotal
    s.salesorderid
from
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader s
    inner join  Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd
        on s.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrerID
group by 
    s.SalesPersonID
    s.salesorderid
order by
    orderTotal desc
```

in SQL server you can just ask for a limited number of rows with the top function (this can give you the highest order value when sorted correctly). this can be used with a group by that adds all the line totals together that have the same values in the columns being grouped by.

Comment: @PrabhatG needlessly cryptic comment. needs modification

Comment: Does it? I ran it. Output is wrong. `s.salesorderid` shouldn't be in group by clause, as it messes the output.

Comment: @PrabhatG "I want to show Which employee has sold for the highest order value" I take this to mean they are looking for the employee that sold the highest value order.. that requires grouping by sales order id no?

Comment: @PrabhatG fwiw that would be a logic error not a syntax one any ways ;) the missing commas are a syntax error XD

Comment: @gordatron: I interpret it as, employee who has maximum LineTotal. Anyway, since OP has marked yours right, I guess your interpretation is more meaningful than mine. Cheers. and Syntax error is clearly visible, nothing 'crypted' :P I was just not sure about logic.

Comment: @PrabhatG max line total doesn't require a group by or aggregate functions.. max total sales would. and a non cryptic comment would have been "by the way there are a couple of commas missing" - or is there another syntax error.. i just don't know as you refuse to stoop to such a low level.. ah well i guess i will have to just be honoured that you took the time to tell me i was wrong.

Comment: @gordatron By max line total, I meant sum of all line total. nevermind

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do, to get the total by each Sales Person. Order by the `Sum(sd.LineTotal)` descending to get the Highest Value.

```
select s.SalesPersonID ,COUNT(sd.SalesOrderID) as count,sum(sd.LineTotal ) as orderTotal  
from Sales.SalesOrderHeader s 
Inner Join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd ON s.SalesOrderID=sd.SalesOrderID 
group by s.SalesPersonID 
order by 3 Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

We appreciate your effort. However, there is a simpler way to get your answer.

```
SELECT 
-- TOP 1   //to get highest order total
 s.SalesPersonID
 ,COUNT(sd.SalesOrderID) as Total_Count
 ,sum(sd.LineTotal) as orderTotal  
FROM 
  Sales.SalesOrderHeader s Inner Join Sales.SalesOrderDetail sd 
  ON s.SalesOrderID=sd.SalesOrderID 
GROUP BY s.SalesPersonID 
HAVING s.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY sum(sd.LineTotal) desc
```

What I am doing is, joining `SalesOrderHeader` with `SalesOrderDetail` through `SalesOrderId` and using [aggregate functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql) to get desired result.

`Order by` is use to get highest value first. `Top 1` is use to get only desired output.